# invertible elements in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading a proof in the book **Basic Abstract Algebra** (by P. B Bhattacharya, S. R. Nagpaul, S. K. Jain page 172) and I'm trying to understand the proof from a  result. The result states:

let x be a nonzero element of a ring R with 1. if there exist a unique element $y \in R$  such that xyx=x, then xy=1=yx; that is,x is invertible in R.

Solution: 
let $xr=0$, $r \in R$. Then $x(y+r)x=x$ and hence y+r=y. Thus, $xr=0$ implies $r=0$. Now $xyx=x$  gives $x(yx-1)=0$. Thus, $yx-1=0$, which completes the solution

My question is why do they have to prove $xr=0 \Rightarrow r=0$ in the solution?

Comment: From only $x(yx-1)=0$ it cannot be concluded yet that $yx-1=0$. This because $x$ could be a zero-divisor.

Comment: I reviewed my comment a bit. Do you understand it now?

Comment: @drhab Yes I do, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: It's not that we HAVE to prove it, but it seems evident why it is useful from the proof...

Comment: If citing a page number for a book... it would be good to tell what the book is too (not that we still need that information. I just wondered if you realized you did this.)

Comment: @rschwieb As I said "Basic Abstract Algebra" is the name of the book, but I  probably should have added the authors as well to make less confusion.

Comment: @stenvikteam Authors and some sort of capitalization or italicization... it is not easy to discern whether or not you are talking about a title. You can still add that by the way using the edit feature, and you probably should...

Comment: @rschwieb ok, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @stenvikteam Ahh, that's better. In fact, that was my undergraduate abstract algebra text too. In fact, the prof of the class was S.K. Jain :)

Comment: @rschwieb oh cool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing that $x$ isn't a left zero divisor provides a lever to show that the one-sided inverse is two-sided.

To be honest, I think the whole strategy is difficult to anticipate before you have seen the trick. The best justification I can come up with is it's like learning to walk before you run: "if you want to prove it's left invertible and can't, can you at least show it's not a left zero divisor? " That is *necessary* for it to be left invertible, so it would be a step in the right direction.

Then after it turns out to be true: "Oh look, now I can show it is left invertible using that fact with $x(yx-1)=xyx-x=0$..."

Comment: So if I have understood you correctly you are saying that if every nonzero $ x\in R$ fulfills the $xyx=x$ for a unique y requirement the Ring is a division ring?

Comment: @stenvikteam Originally that's what I was saying because I was thinking of a different, yet similar problem :) The edits I've made should have corrected this... let me know what you think.

Comment: To be honest the analogy just makes me even more confused as I'm not used to using the term regular. I very much appreciate that you tried explaining it to me though. It might become clearer as I work more with Ring Theory.

Comment: @stenvikteam Sorry: "right regular" is a synonym for "not a right zero divisor."  Clearly if $x$ is left invertible, it is not a right zero divisor (if $xr=0$, then $r=yxr=0$) I'm just saying that right regularity is a step in the right direction because it is *necessary* (but not always sufficient) for $x$ to be left invertible.

Comment: @stenvikteam Made a few edits to try to address your comment.

Comment: @ rschwieb I'm just getting more confused.  Correct me if I'm wrong but x is left invertible if $\exists y \in R $such that$ y \ast x = e$ And x is a right zero divisor if $ \exists r \in R$ such that  $ r \ast x = 0$ where $ r, x \neq 0$.

And did you mean $rx=0$ instead of $xr=0$?

Comment: just to let you know I'm taking the train soon, so I won't be able to respond to you the next 4 hours.

Comment: @stenvikteam Sorry again, yes, I was mixing terms. I should have said "right regular" is a synonym for "not a left zero divisor". The same thing happens with "left invertible" being a synonym for "a right unit."  Unfortunately without careful thought these are easy to mix up. I think, definitively, I should say that **"a left invertible element is not a left zero divisor"** (alternatively *is a right regular element*)  It was very early in the morning EDT when I wrote all this.

Comment: I really like your profile picture. May I ask were it is taken from?

Comment: @stenvikteam It is from a webcomic (search pbfcomics) and the reason I am not linking is because it is not always appropriate for all ages or viewers. Please bear this in mind if you decide to look for it. The one the picture is Safe For Work (comic /199 in the url)